# Is it possible to check a .htaccess file using the -t option of the apache2 command?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, validation

I've got a `.htaccess` file that I copied from one Apache HTTPD server and deployed onto another.  Unfortunately, I foolishly didn't check the version of the destination server and just put the file in place; the site stopped working because it's Apache 2.4 and the file has 2.2 syntax.  So I quickly reverted it to the previous version and hoped that nobody noticed!

Now, of course, I'm paranoid.

I tried copying the broken-on-2.4 version elsewhere and using `apache2 -t .htaccess` to find out what's wrong, but I get this error:

```
apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/.htaccess: No such file or directory
```

If I supply the full path (i.e. `apache2 -t /path/to/it/.htaccess`) I get:

```
AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
```

This error [*appears* to be unrelated](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/ah00534-httpd-configuration-error-no-mpm-loaded-4175499888/) but I get the same error message and exit code (1) regardless of whether or not there's an error in the `.htaccess` file.

So my question is: can I use `apache2 -t [...]` to test a `.htaccess` file, and if not, what can I use instead (aside from the manual)?  There is [this site](http://www.htaccesscheck.com/) but it doesn't seem to allow me to say what version of Apache to check against.

Comment: There is this page for all config changes from Apache 2.2 to 2.4: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html . And, afaik no unfortunately you cannot check the .htaccess files with `-t`. Only the configuration files that are read at server startup.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found out how to do what I asked, but I have come up with a workaround.

I created a new directory on the server and put the incompatible `.htaccess` file in there.  I then accessed the directory via my browser whilst `tail -f`ing the error log (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`) to see what the problem was.